# Google cloud vision face detection API with local files

Tags: python, google-cloud-vision

I am integrating my camera with Google cloud vision API so that I can count the total number of people in a room. But the API is returning only 10 responses.

In order to get more responses I added the field `max_results` in `features`. After adding the `max_results` field it is returning more than 10 responses, but then I get the problem that it is only accepting an image with a 'URI' and I am unable to give it an image present on my system. It is only accepting images present on the internet with an image address like in the piece of code below. Now how can I specify an image present on my system instead of giving URI?

My python code for taking image and features:

> response = client.annotate_image({'image': {'source': {'image_uri':'http://im.rediff.com/news/2016/jan/26republic-day1.jpg'}},  'features': [{'type': vision.enums.Feature.Type.FACE_DETECTION,'max_results':40}],})

Comment: It's not clear whether these are two separate issues, one of which you've fixed, or whether they're only a problem in combination. Ignoring max_results, are you able to use a local file? If so, what happens when you then add max_results to the request?

Comment: There is only one problem, that is I am unable to use my local file as it is taking only URI of an image and local files don't have any URI.

Comment: In that case, you should change your question to *only* mention that part, as it has absolutely nothing to do with max_results.

Comment: Next read the documentation here: https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-usage-python That shows you how to upload a local file.

Comment: I know how to upload a local file but In the above code instead of 'image_uri' I want to keep my local file and when I am trying to do so it is not detecting any faces.

Comment: So you need to modify the example on the web page to specify the features you want and the max results. Or modify the code you've already got to use `image` as loaded via the example instead of using the version with `image_uri`. Basically you haven't show what you've tried in terms of using a local file and specifying face detection. See also: https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/detecting-faces

Comment: this is my modified code(not working) =>  file_name = os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(__file__),
    '/mnt/c/Users/DELL/Desktop/EIS_gpro/test11.jpg')         
    response = client.annotate_image({'image': file_name,'features':[---],})

Comment: this is the response I have got in my terminal  ==>  message: "Unsupported URI protocol specified: /mnt/c/Users/DELL/Desktop/EIS_gpro/test11.jpg."

Comment: You're specifying the file name as the image. That's not going to work. But all of this should be in the question, not in comment.s

Answer (score 0):

Working snippet:

```
import io
import os


# Imports the Google Cloud client library
from google.cloud import vision
from google.cloud.vision import types

# Instantiates a client
client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()

# The name of the image file to annotate
file_name = os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(__file__),
    'face.jpeg')

# Loads the image into memory
with io.open(file_name, 'rb') as image_file:
    content = image_file.read()

image = types.Image(content=content)

response = client.annotate_image({'image': image, 'features': [{'type': vision.enums.Feature.Type.FACE_DETECTION,'max_results':40}],})

print response

# Print joy likelihood
for face in response.face_annotations:
        print(face.joy_likelihood)
```

Basically, pass the image and not just the filename